# Magento Product import error - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column ‘attribute_id’ cannot be null

Tags: magento

I am having an issue uploading a large csv of products.

It goes through the check on then after then import says: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column ‘attribute_id’ cannot be null

After this has done I have checked the products page and they are all there but do not seem to be in the categories, do not show in search and even if I manually enable the categories do not show.

Any ideas? Really stuck!

Comment: The error says that you are attempting to insert the record without `attribute_id`, where attribute_id is a mandatory field.

Comment: Thanks Kalpesh, so would the solution be to add a column for attribute_id in the csv?

Answer (score 6):

There is a value missing in "_media_attribute_id"

check all column and insert "88" where it is missing.

It solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Invalid `attribute_id` is associated with custom attributes.

You need to check that 1) all the attribute fields referenced in your csv - lets use **Color** just as an example - have been set up as attributes in Magento *(Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes)*. Similarly, you need to make sure that any custom attributes that have been added and configured to be required are in your csv.

The attributes which Magento will be expecting will ultimately depend on the attribute_set you tell Magento to use for those products - also part of your csv. Attribute sets can be managed similarly under *Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute Sets*

You then need to make sure that all the attribute values you are attempting to import and are mentioned in the csv, actually appear as values for those attributes in Magento. For exmaple, if in Magento the available values for the attribute **Color** were only *Red* and *Blue* - and you were trying to import *Yellow* under this heading, it would throw the error you mentioned. Note these are also case sensitive. Magento will error on *blue* if it is expecting *Blue*.

**Products not appearing in Search would be an unrelated issue...**

In your csv, check under the heading "visibility" that you imported the value "Catalog, Search" - it might be that you have imported them as either "Catalog" or "Not visible individually" which would explain them not appearing (I assume at this point they have been uploaded as enabled or you have manually enabled them before searching!)

Comment: Ben is correct.  Although I thought Dataflow added attribute option values (not the attribute_codes themselves).  As an alternative, I would recommend Magmi for doing mass imports.  It handles importing a mass range of product, attribute and other Magento dynamics very quickly: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for taking the time to write that. I understand what you are saying however 1) I am not using any custom attributes 2) The products which upload do have Catalog, Search - I have uploaded some sample data here - http://www.sendspace.com/file/ysqfc5 - any more ideas?

Comment: I have realised that if I go into the product, do nothing, and save it the products work. However I do not want to do this for several thousand products everytime I upload, how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case, some products didn't have "_media_attribute_id" field populated.

Answer (score 0):

I received this same error when I hadn't set up my attribute and attribute set prior to importing a configurable item using said non-existent attribute.

Edit: Thus, creating and configuring the attribute and attribute set from the Magento dashboard resulted in Magmi not throwing this error.

Comment: You may want to reword your answer, it could be read as a "I'm having this problem too" comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem..Then i solved with filling `'88'` under `'_media_attribute_id'` column.